# Moment Generating Functions for beginners

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, moment-generating-functions

Problem: Let  $X$  be a random variable with MGF  $M_X(2)=\frac{1}{3}e^{-t}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{2}e^{2t}$. What is  $P(X≤1)$?

I tried taking $P(X=0)$ and $P(X=1)$ and plugging those numbers into the equation for $t$ but that didn't work.

I tried:
$$M_X(2)=\frac{1}{3}e^{-(0)}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{2}e^{2(0)}=0.3333+0.16666+0.5=0.999999 (wrong)$$
$$M_X(2)=\frac{1}{3}e^{-(1)}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{2}e^{2(1)}=0.1226+0.16666+3.6945=4.1944 (wrong)$$.

I might be confusing what $t$ is with what $X$ is.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Your formula is unreadable. Do to mean $M_X(2)=13e^{-t}+16+12e^{2t}$.

Comment: Yes I updated the formula accordingly above.

Comment: I don't think that's a valid mgf. can you check?

Comment: $M_X(t) = \mathbb{E} e^{tX}, M_X(2)$ should be a specific value , why function?@Fototekt

Comment: @Song Sorry I had been going all day and was extremely tired last night.  Didn't even notice the fractions weren't right.

Comment: If $M_X(t)$ denotes your MGF, then can you ascertain what the distribution is? (In general this would not be so easy, but since you have $M_X(t)$ as a sum of exponentials you should be able to deduce the pmf by inspection.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If... the MGF is the following

$$M_X(t)=\frac{1}{3}e^{-t}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{2}e^{2t}$$

This is the MGF of hte following discrete rv

$$ X =
\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{6},  & \text{if $x=-1$ } \\
\frac{1}{6},  & \text{if $x=0$ } \\
\frac{3}{6},  & \text{if $x=2$ } 
\end{cases}$$

Thus

$$\mathbb{P}[X\leq 1]=\frac{3}{6}$$

Comment: That is what I was missing.  Now MGFs make more sence.  Sometimes its the small things that are missing to link the whole puzzle to gether.

Comment: I keep getting hung up on what $t$ is for

Comment: You answered yet another post that get's closed as a poor quality question, tommik.  That reflects badly on you.

Comment: I have added to the question to provide detail.  It was lazy on my part not to add what I tried as part of the question in more detail.